# This set-cookie was not stored due to user preference

Tags: google-chrome, setcookie

I have set a cookie from an api and returned it as a response. But the latest version of chrome beta is not letting me to store the cookie. I have also set the `SameSite="None"` and `Secure` for considering third party cookies. But this is not getting stored.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check `chrome://settings/content/cookies`. You want to ensure that:

- *"Allow sites to save and read cookie data (recommended)"* is **enabled**
- *"Block third-party cookies"* is **disabled**
- Check the other settings there to ensure that the site is not on the "Block" list.

You should also check that you don't have any extensions that are affecting cookie behaviour. A quick way of generally testing this is to try in Incognito Mode or by creating a new Chrome profile.

[image: chrome://settings/content/cookies settings page]

Comment: How do I store the 3rd party cookies if "Block third-party cookies" is enabled? I have set flags `SameSite=None` and `Secure=true`

Comment: If the user has chosen to block third-party cookies, then your cookie will not be set. You should add some messaging in your site's UI to explain to the user that certainly functionality may not work if they block those cookies.