# Cross Origin httponly cookie with nodejs and fetch

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, httponly, cookie-httponly

I have a question regarding a cross origin httponly cookie, I have created a very simple express example

```
const express = require("express");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const app = express();
const port = 5000;
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "{frontend-url}");
  res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
  res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, *");
  return next();
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.cookie("auth", true, {
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: false,
    secure: true,
  });

  res.redirect("{frontend-url}");
});

app.get("/epc", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.cookies["auth"]);
  return res.json({ auth: req.cookies["auth"] });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at: ${port}`);
});
```

I am using ngrok for testing it and also have my frontend with a static site builder created, I make a fetch request like the one below:

```js
    fetch("{cookie-creator-server-url}/epc", {
      credentials: "include",
    });
```

I also first go to the **{cookie-creator-server-url}/** which should add the cookie and redirect to the **{frontend-url}** and in the **{frontend-url}** the fetch request should also pass the cookie to the **{cookie-creator-server-url}** however sometimes the cookie is not saved, sometimes the cookie will not be sent or sometimes (on firefox) the cookie gets sent but I can not see it in my browser cookies

in case that anyone already has done a cross origin httponly cookie with express please help me identify where I am doing somthing wrong

thank you

---

### Update 1:

I changed the sameSite variable to "none" and now it is working on Chrome and Firefox, however on the incognito mode and Iridium I am getting the error "this cookie was blocked due to user preferences"

which based on [How to fix "This Set-Cookie was blocked due to user preferences" in Chrome? (Stackoverflow SSO Login / Ajax CORS request)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62578201/how-to-fix-this-set-cookie-was-blocked-due-to-user-preferences-in-chrome-sta) is gonna be a default behaviour in future for Chrome, can someone please provide more information on this topic? is there any work around for it?